# sublime text 2 word wrap setting doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I put this preference.sublime-settings,

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
     [
        "Vintage"
     ]

        "word_wrap": true
}
```

But the error comes out like this when I save it: `Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:7:2`

what's wrong with this?

Comment: In *[JSON syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON_sample)* you need a comma after every property of an object. In this case you need a comma after the character *]*

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I should have edited Preference.sublime-settings-`Default` instead of `User`. That was the problem.

Comment: You should never have to edit the Default file. Check the comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be facing this problem because the previous property didn't end with a comma. Make sure that there is a comma before you enter any new property. Like there is after `font_size` in the following illustration.

```
"font_size": 11,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"word_wrap": true
```